# Filter Datagrid view with data from sql with int[] Array values

Tags: c#, arrays, wpf, datagrid

I am trying to Learning C# and I have this Inventory system that I am building but I am having a problem how to filter my datagridvew from an public int[] array values.

This is my Code:

```
public int[] cartConfirm_lst = new int[20];
public void loadDV()
{
        string connStr = "Data Source=731LPTP\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=ACCSIS;Integrated Security=True";
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr);
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("SELECT * from Orders");
        comm.Connection = conn;
        SqlDataReader dr = comm.ExecuteReader();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Load(dr);
        //Code for DataView filter              
        DataTable filteredTable = dt.Clone();
        DataView dv = dt.DefaultView;         
        foreach(int x in cartConfirm_lst)           
            dv.RowFilter = "Order_ID in (" + cartConfirm_lst[x] + ")";
        filteredTable = dv.ToTable();

        cartConfirm_dgv.DataSource = filteredTable;
}
```

Any Help would be greatly appreciated, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `RowFilter`

```
 (cartConfirm_dgv.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = "Order_ID IN (1, 2, 3)"
```